# Fake dynamic files in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to run `pocketlint` on all `**/*.js` files.

```
.PHONY: lint_js2

LINT_JS = $(wildcard static/js/*.js static/js/**/*.js)
LINT_JS_TARGETS = $(addprefix lint__,$(LINT_JS))

#.PHONY: $(LINT_JS_TARGETS)

lint_js2: $(LINT_JS_TARGETS)
    echo $<

lint__%: %
    pocketlint $<
```

However, I get this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `lint__static/js/ad_list.js', needed by `lint_js2'.  Stop.
```

1. Why `lint__static/js/ad_list.js` is not captured by `lint__%`?
2. If I uncomment second `.PHONY`, it echoes `lint__static/js/ad_list.js`, but does not invoke `pocketlint static/js/ad_list.js`. Why?

If my approach is wrong, what would be the right approach? Since tasks are independent, I would appreciate if `make -j50` would do what I am expecting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what is intended: does `pocketlint` write a file named `lint__static/js/ad_list.js`, or is that really a phony filename?  Anyway...

1. Reread the second paragraph of [How Patterns Match](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html):

   > When the target pattern **does not contain a slash** (and it usually does not), **directory names in the file names are removed from the file name before it is compared with the target prefix and suffix**. After the comparison of the file name to the target pattern, the directory names, along with the slash that ends them, are added on to the prerequisite file names generated from the pattern rule's prerequisite patterns and the file name.

   In short, `%` generally matches just a filename, not a pathname with slashes in it.  So `lint__static/js/ad_list.js` is not captured because actually it is only `ad_list.js` that is being matched against `lint__%`.

   If you can arrange it so that the output files from `pocketlint` are `static/js/lint__ad_list.js` etc, then this could be made to work:

   ```
   LINT_JS_TARGETS = $(foreach f,$(LINT_JS),$(dir $f)lint__$(notdir $f))

   lint__%: %
       pocketlint $<
   ```

   Alternatively you can make `%` match pathnames by having the target pattern be a pathname (containing a slash):

   ```
   LINT_JS_TARGETS = $(addprefix linted/,$(LINT_JS))

   linted/%: %
       pocketlint $<
   ```

   This time `%` = `static/js/ad_list.js` does match the pattern rule.

   In either case, you're going to have to have `pocketlint` produce output (if indeed it produces output) named differently than `lint__static/*`.
2. Implicit rule search is suppressed for phony targets (see [Phony Targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html), paragraph 5).  So the rule involving `pocketlint` is never considered when `lint__static/js/ad_list.js` is phony.

   It's not obvious why the result is *Nothing to be done for (phony)* `lint__static/js/ad_list.js` rather than *No rule to make target* `lint__static/js/ad_list.js`, but I wouldn't lose sleep over it!

Comment: No, pocketlint does not produce any output. `lint__` is a fake target.

Comment: @Motiejus Then I think I showed you a couple of ways that will work.  However if pocketlint doesn't write an output file then presumably you're running it to get messages on stdout/stderr, which means the tasks aren't really independent: the messages will be jumbled up with `make -j50`.  So really it'd be hard to improve on the simple `lint_js2: for f in $(LINT_JS); do pocketlint $$f; done`.